# Karma / Jasmine - Testing an "On" Listener in an Angular JS Controller

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner

I have the following code in my controller:

```
angular.element($window).on("resize", function(){
        if($scope.getScreenWidth() >= $scope.minScreenWidth){
            $scope.showNotification("notificationOne");
        }
        else{
            $scope.showNotification("notificationTwo");
        }
});
```

The above will show a message on the user's screen anytime he or she resizes the browser.  The message shown is different depending on the current width of the screen.

Is there anywhere to test the above code using Jasmine / Karma?  If not, how should I write the controller snippet above so that I can test the functionality?

Answer (score 3):

You should try to avoid DOM manipulation within a controller... That being said, you can probably put the resize listener outside your controller and use $rootScope to broadcast the resize. module.run might be a good place to kick it off:

```
mod.run(function ($window, $rootScope, $timeout) {
    angular.element($window).on("resize", function () {
        //broadcast your event of interest
        $timeout(function () {
            $rootScope.$broadcast("myApp.windowResize");
        }, 0);
    });
});
```

Then in your controller, you can subscribe to the myApp.windowResize event:

```
$scope.$on("myApp.windowResize", function () {
    var screenWidth = $scope.getScreenWidth();

    if(screenWidth >= $scope.minScreenWidth){
        $scope.showNotification("notificationOne");
    }
    else{
        $scope.showNotification("notificationTwo");
    }
});

$scope.showNotification = function (msg) {
    $scope.message = msg;
}
```

From here, it would be trivial to broadcast this same event from a Jasmine/Karma test. You will also have to keep in mind that $scope.getScreenWidth might need to be mocked out to return different values so you can assert whether showNotification has been called with "notificationOne" or "notificationTwo". For example:

```
describe("hello controller test", function () {
    var $scope;
    beforeEach(module("myApp"));
    beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope) {
        $scope = $rootScope.$new();
    }));

    it("should have notificationOne", inject(function($controller, $rootScope) {
        $controller("MainController", {$scope: $scope});

        //mock screen width call: Always return a greater or equal value for notificationOne.
        $scope.getScreenWidth = function () {
            return $scope.minScreenWidth;
        }

        $rootScope.$broadcast("myApp.windowResize");
        $rootScope.$apply();

        expect($scope.message).toBeDefined();
        expect($scope.message).toBe("notificationOne");
    }));
});
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8BWEa/) with the demo app.

Comment: This is probably the 'Angular' way of doing it, but the fact that you have to write *this* much more code just to adhere to 'Angular' principles is really an indication that this and related issues should be redone by the Angular team

Comment: Its only a few more lines of code to write -- just the module.run setup. The rest of the code you would presumably have; your Controller is just listening for a different event... Again, you don't have to adhere to this, just subscribe to the window.onresize in your controller - but as you know out that limits the testing surface more (just like doing UI specific things in other frameworks would restrict ability to unit test).